# Bad Request (400) message every time I try to build my Docker Ubuntu 16:04 image

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I am attempting to build a docker image with the requirements specified in `requirements.txt`. However, upon trying to build the file, I get the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-atm/libatm1_2.5.1-1.5_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/popt/libpopt0_1.16-10_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap-ng/libcap-ng0_0.7.7-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

I have attempted to change the mirror, I have checked the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list, I have tried to add the flag `--fix-missing` and tried to build the image with `--no-cache` all to no avail.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Siddhanth Ajri "y2jsiddajri@gmail.com"

RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# Changing to US archives of UBUNTU
RUN sed -i'' 's/archive\.ubuntu\.com/us\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    curl \
    git

#RUN add-apt-repository universe

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git 

RUN apt-get install python3.7

RUN apt-get install python3-pip

# Upgrade pip to 20.x
RUN pip3 install -U pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /
```

None of the mentioned solutions I've found so far have been able to fix this issue for me.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se] or 
[su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which helped me here: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57567-Ubuntu-problems-on-update

You can let apt-get to regenerate lists cache using:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

I get these errors all the time and for me it varies by ISP and/or geographic repos.
I usually run the same command immediately and it suddenly fixes itself. Maybe slow DNS Lookup or something.

Of course inside a Dockerfile it fails and stops you building and rebuilding simply starts the command over again.

Heres how i solved the issue in Dockerfile

Replace any apt commands like so....

Example Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils software-properties-common nano wget curl
RUN apt install apache2 mariadb-server -y


....
```

New Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN set -eux; \
for i in $(seq 1 5); do \
    if apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y; then \
        break; \
    else \
        echo "Error: apt-get failed (attempt $i of 5). Retrying..." >&2; \
        sleep 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if [ "$i" = 5 ]; then \
    echo "Error: apt-get failed after 5 attempts." >&2; \
    exit 1; \
fi

RUN set -eux; \
for i in $(seq 1 5); do \
    if apt-get install -y apt-utils software-properties-common nano wget curl; then \
        break; \
    else \
        echo "Error: apt-get failed (attempt $i of 5). Retrying..." >&2; \
        sleep 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if [ "$i" = 5 ]; then \
    echo "Error: apt-get failed after 5 attempts." >&2; \
    exit 1; \
fi

RUN set -eux; \
for i in $(seq 1 5); do \
    if apt install apache2 mariadb-server -y; then \
        break; \
    else \
        echo "Error: apt-get failed (attempt $i of 5). Retrying..." >&2; \
        sleep 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if [ "$i" = 5 ]; then \
    echo "Error: apt-get failed after 5 attempts." >&2; \
    exit 1; \
fi
....
```

Here the apt command is run and if it has an error it retries up to a maximum of 5 times.
This has worked for me 99% of the time.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error.  It was self-inflicted.

I had set up my terminal to intercept ( and proxy ) all network traffic.  Turning that env variable off fixed the Docker Build:

```
unset https_proxy
```